# Can ping specific website but cannot browse to it - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet, browser

I've been working on a specific website over the last two days and everything's been running fine until a certain point I could no longer browse to it any more.

EDIT: When I do browse to it from any browser, it returns "This web page is not available" and similar in other browsers.

I can ping it, I can browse to it from my wife's laptop, but I cannot browse the site from my own machine any more.

EDIT: From my wife's machine, I have plugged a 3G modem in which uses a different network.

I've tried a number of solutions I have found on the net including releasing my IP address, Flushing the DNS, restarting machine.

I am running Windows 7 Pro. This happens across all A-Grade browsers

Many thanks

Comment: Your problem description is very vague. You just say you "cannot browse" the site. Why not? What happens when you try? Do you get an error message?

Comment: When you ping it from your PC, does ping show same IP-address for the server as is shown when you ping the name from your wife's laptop? Do you have a proxy set? Are you using a different internet connection?

Comment: Added an EDIT David and Red.

Comment: No proxy Red only difference was that my wife's laptop is running of a 3G modem as opposed to my ADSL connection.

Comment: This is the address I am trying to get to http://goo.gl/wxcSA

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Shift+R?

Comment: Oddly enough, I just switched the Firewall off and was able to access the site, albeit, SUPER slowly. I don't quite understand why it would have worked well for almost two days and then collapses altogether. The last thing I remember doing was adding a Form using one of the WordPress plugins, but I had been doing this for a little  while and I have used this plugins many times.

Comment: Nope. Switched the Firewall back on, refreshed the site and then it wouldn't load. Switched it back off again and not able to access the site.

Comment: when you ping the site and you see the ip address returned, what happens when you enter the ip address in the browser? If she is able to browse through 3g and you can't from another connection, I would suspect your gateway on your machine]

Comment: Hi Datatoo. I tried using just the IP address and get the same result. What baffles me, is that up until it happened I had made no changes to the network settings at all. And I can browse all other website except for this one.

Comment: Miraculously, out of nowhere the site started working again for no apparent reason. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one has been resolved, at about 11pm that night, it started working again for no apparent reason.